# CakePHP 2 & Translate Behavior: save multiple translations in a single form

Tags: validation, internationalization, cakephp-2.0, locale

Its possibile save multiple translations of the same field in a single form?
I have a model with Behavior Translate to translate the name field. The three translations (deu, eng, ita) are properly recorded in the i18n table but the field is not properly validated! Any suggestions?

app/Model/Category.php

```
class Category extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Translate' => array('name' => 'TranslateName'));
    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Error notempty',
            ),
        ),
    );
    ...
```

app/View/Categories/admin_edit.ctp

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Category');
echo $this->Form->input('Category.id');
echo $this->Form->input('Category.name.deu', array('label' => __d('Category', 'Name Deu')));
echo $this->Form->input('Category.name.eng', array('label' => __d('Category', 'Name Eng')));
echo $this->Form->input('Category.name.ita', array('label' => __d('Category', 'Name Ita')));
echo $this->Form->end(__d('app', 'Submit'));
?>
```

app/View/Controller/CategoriesController.php

```
if ($this->Category->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__d('Category', 'The category has been saved'));
} else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__d('Category', 'The category could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar Problem

But you can try out this - it should solve it for you: https://github.com/zoghal/cakephp-MultiTranslateBehavior